# How to compare time in Freemarker?

Tags: time, compare, freemarker

I have time in following format:

2017-02-08T08:59:22+00:00

2017-02-08T09:00:55+00:00

How can I compare these two times using Freemarker ?

Answer (score 2):

Like `t1 < t2`, `t1 == t2`, etc. That assuming that you get those timestamps as `java.util.Date`-s, not as strings. If you receive them as strings, first of all see if the Java side can be changed to fix that. If it can't be, you  can use `someString?datetime('iso')` to convert them to `java.util.Date` in the template.

Answer (score 1):

If those timestamps are representations of `java.util.Date` objects you can use `.before()` and `.after()` java methods.

```
<#if date1.before(date2) >
    ...
</#if>
```

Same approach if you are using [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or other libraries that cover date comparisons.